# How to use ScalaJS-bundler with JsDependencies (WebJars)

Tags: scala, scala.js, scalajs-bundler, playscalajs

I have an existing project with Scala.JS (client) + Play framework*/sbt-web (server). The project uses some WebJars + ProvidedJS, whose are included by `jsDependencies ++= Seq(…)`, using the sbt-jsdependencies plugin. They are included in the `…-jsdeps.js` file, which is used in the server project.

Now, I am trying to add some other libary using ScalaJS-bundler. After adding the plugin, I have a `…-bundle.js` file, which seems to contain everything I need except the jsdependencies. Furthermore, while the jsdeps is generated in the client project, it is no longer exported to the server project, so I cannot just use both.

Is there a way to use both jsdependencies and scalajs-bundler at the same time? I don't want to immediately switch to scalajs-bundler and rather do it gradually.

---

*) Well, the Play framework is actually not used in the production. I use sbt-web and export static files. The Play framework is used just for development.